# JiBX generates binding that ignores attribute namespace

Tags: java, xsd, code-generation, jibx

I have the following schema (fragment):

```
<xs:complexType name="partnerPaymentsItemType">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="changeTime" type="dateTime"/>
        <xs:element name="statusId" type="shortId"/>
        <xs:element name="paymentPointId" type="shortString"/>
        <xs:element name="money" type="currency"/>
        <xs:element name="paymentDestination" type="shortString"/>
        <xs:element name="paymentDestinationType" type="shortId"/>
        <xs:element name="subagentId" type="shortId" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xs:element name="discountCardNumber" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xs:element name="amountAll" type="currency" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xs:element name="rewardPercent" type="percentAmount" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xs:element name="rewardPercentValue" type="percentAmount" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="paymentTime" use="required" type="dateTime"/>
    <xs:attribute name="externalId" use="required" type="id"/>
    <xs:attribute name="registeredId" use="required" type="id"/>
</xs:complexType>
```

I use JibX Codegen tool to generate sources from it, and then to compile binding that should allow me to unmarshal XML to Java objects. Here is my codegen settings:

```
<schema-set xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        delete-annotations="true"
        prefer-inline="false"
        generate-all="true"
        show-schema="true"
        type-substitutions="xs:date xs:string"
        package="here.lays.my.package">
    <class-decorator     class="org.jibx.schema.codegen.extend.SerializableDecorator"/>
</schema-set>
```

Later, I try to parse an XML document which has namespace prefixes for both tags and attributes, which results an exception saying

> Missing required attribute "paymentTime"

Debugging through JiBX sources shown that it tries to look for attribute with no namespace and name "paymentTime" in a document, while a document has an attribute with a namespace mapped to URL, and not able to find it of course.

I have decompiled binding with JAD and it searches for attribute with null namespace:

```
public static PartnerPaymentsItemType JiBX_beeline_binding_unmarshalAttr_1_93(PartnerPaymentsItemType arg1, UnmarshallingContext arg2)
    throws JiBXException
{
    arg2.pushTrackedObject(arg1);
    arg1;
    arg1.setPaymentTime(arg2.attributeText(null, "paymentTime"));
    arg1.setExternalId(Utility.parseLong(WhitespaceConversions.trim(arg2.attributeText(null, "externalId"))));
    arg1.setRegisteredId(Utility.parseLong(WhitespaceConversions.trim(arg2.attributeText(null, "registeredId"))));
    arg2.popObject();
    return arg1;
}
```

I would be grateful for any advise that could help resolving the issue - like, why JiBX generated such mapping, how to make it respect attribute namespace, and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JiBX behavior was actually correct, namespace prefixes for attributes were not intended based on xsd.

Actual solution was to replace JiBX with XJC/JAXB and separate schema for the entity where I needed namespace prefixes for attributes.